# Deployments of Postgres to AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql

How do you deploy schema changes locally to a Postgres DB?

For MS SQL projects in VS you can "publish" but no idea what the equivalent is for Postgres.

Comment: What is the format of your migration file? The most basic way would be via `psql`, but most web frameworks have support for real management systems (eg flyway).

Comment: @jordanm I'm very new to Postgres and not sure what a migration file is. Is there a way to generate a psql diff that can be manually applied?

Comment: What framework are you using for the application that is accessing the database? Most frameworks will include or recommend a method for creating and applying migration files. It is a feature of most ORMs.

Comment: @jordanm aspnet core 6 and EF

Comment: That's not a tech stack i'm personally familiar with, but a quick look at the docs I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: @jordanm Your link is correct - OP should use EF migrations to apply these. I can't see the link to AWS for this question.

Comment: @jordanm Thank you! I just needed something to point me in the right direction. I'll start digging into EF migrations.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Sounds like there isn't one if it's just running psql directly on the server.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at technologies like Flyway or DBUp. They're meant for managing these kinds of database changes & deployments.

Comment: @GrantFritchey OP is using EF, EF migrations is what they should be using not any other tool.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Sorry, I meant to say there doesn't appear to be a link with AWS as my original question assumed and as you pointed out. I was just agreeing :)